# Cannot install autotest-fsevent or rs-fsevent; getting ld error but xcode is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos, ld

Here's what I'm getting:

> $ sudo gem install autotest-fsevent
>   Password: Building native extensions. 
>   This could take a while... ERROR: 
>   Error installing autotest-fsevent: 
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> /Volumes/SSD/Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb ld: can't open output file
>   for writing: /Volumes/Macintosh
>   HD/Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.4/bin/fsevent_sleep,
>   errno=2 collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status extconf.rb:30:in `':
>   Compilation of fsevent_sleep failed
>   (see README) (RuntimeError)

The README says this:

> TROUBLESHOOTING:
>
> Compilation of fsevent_sleep Failed
>
> Make sure you have Xcode (Mac OS X
>   Development Suite) installed.

I have installed the latest xcode and even re-installed it just in case something was missing.

Anyone know how to at least troubleshoot this further.  I did hear some someone it it could be path related.  But here's the information on the path. I have two drives in the machine, an SSD with the OS on it and a HDD with all my data. I have a symlink on the SSD for my home directory so `/Volumes/SSD/Users/Ross/` points to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Ross`
Is that the issue? Is the space in the Volume name an issue maybe?  How could I get around this?

Comment: `errno=2` means no such file or directory. Does ` /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Ross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.4/bin` exist?

Comment: Also, is your filesystem case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Zen Spiders Blog](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/ZenTest). A lot has changed when it comes to Autotest and Growl. I normally simply add this to my Gemfile (or rvmsudo gem install) depending on?

```
  gem "ZenTest"
  gem "autotest-rails-pure"
  gem "autotest-growl"
  gem "autotest-fsevent"
```

Then add the following to .autotest

```
  require 'autotest/growl'
  require 'autotest/fsevent'
```

Let us know how you get on. All the Best. Remember when you are using RVM you do not SUDO anything. If permissions are denied then simply use RVMSUDO GEM INSTALL.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks, rvmsudo was the trick, I was getting a permission error without sudo.

Comment: You should take a look at http://viget.com/extend/how-why-to-run-autotest-on-your-mac